# MYSQL: SUM with multiple group

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table like this:

```
PRODUCTID      REORDER_QTY      TYPE      ADJUST_TYPE  
-------------  ---------------  --------  -----------------
         4343             2.00  Transfer  ADD              
         4730             2.00  Transfer  ADD              
         4730             2.00  Transfer  ADD              
         4730             1.00  Transfer  DEDUCT           
         3643            20.00  Transfer  ADD              
         3643             3.00  Transfer  DEDUCT
```

how do i write a sql to total up the **REORDER_QTY** by its **PRODUCTID** and also **ADJUST_TYPE**, after that get its balance by sum all the **ADD** and minus the sum all by **DEDUCT**

example sql result output i want:

```
PRODUCTID        TYPE                   Total_Balance
-------------    ----------             ---------------
4730             Transfer               ((SUM the REORDER_QTY by ADD) - (SUM the REORDER_QTY by DEDUCT))
3643             Transfer               ((SUM the REORDER_QTY by ADD) - (SUM the  REORDER_QTY by DEDUCT))
4343             Transfer               ((SUM the REORDER_QTY by ADD) - (SUM the  REORDER_QTY by DEDUCT))
```

any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want conditional aggregation:

```
select productid, type,
       sum(case when adjust_type = 'ADD' then reorder_qty
                when adjust_type = 'DEDUCT' then - reorder_qty
                else 0
           end) as total_balance
from atable
group by productid, type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is mysql, you can do this:

```
select
    productid,
    sum((2 * (adjust_type = 'ADD') - 1) * reorder_qty) as total_balance
from mytable
group by productid
```

This works because in mysql, a boolean condition produces a result of 1 for true and 0 for false, therefore `(2 * (adjust_type = 'ADD') - 1)` produces `1` for `ADD` and `-1` otherwise, making the arithmetic simpler.